# Using CURL send an email through a proxy

Tags: php, email, curl, smtp, fsockopen

I want to make a script in PHP that connects trough a proxy to TELNET at an smtp server.
What i have so far are those two variants :

**1 FSOCKOPEN** (that i cannot proxy this connection)

```
$connection = fsockopen("smtp.comcast.net",25,$errno,$errstr,10);
if(!$connection)
{
    echo "Connection error";
}
else
{
    $command  = "HELO smtp.comcast.net\r\n";
    fwrite($connection,$command);
    while (!feof($connection)) 
    {
        echo fgets($connection, 128)."\n";
    }

    $command  = "AUTH LOGIN\r\n";
    fwrite($connection,$command);
    while (!feof($connection)) 
    {
        echo fgets($connection, 128)."\n";
    }


    $command  = base64_encode("username")."\r\n";
    fwrite($connection,$command);
    while (!feof($connection)) 
    {
        echo fgets($connection, 128)."\n";
    }


    $command  = base64_encode("password")."\r\n";
    fwrite($connection,$command);
    while (!feof($connection)) 
    {
        echo fgets($connection, 128)."\n";
    }

    $command = "QUIT\r\n";
    fwrite($connection,$command);
    while (!feof($connection)) 
    {
        echo fgets($connection, 128)."\n";
    }
}
```

but it is outputting me :

```
220 omta01.emeryville.ca.mail.comcast.net comcast ESMTP server ready
250 omta01.emeryville.ca.mail.comcast.net hello [xx.xx.xx.xx], pleased to meet you
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
```

witch is all good

and another variant

**2 CURL CLASS**

```
class ProxySmtp
{
    private $server;
    private $port;
    private $proxy;
    private $timeout;
    private $curl_connection;

    public function __construct($server,$port,$timeout = 10,$proxy = NULL)
    {
        echo "SERVER: $server:$port \n";
        echo "PROXY: $proxy \n";
        echo "TIMEOUT: $timeout \n";

        // Set the config
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->timeout = $timeout;
        $this->proxy = $proxy;

        // Start the curl
        $this->curl_connection = curl_init($this->server.":".$this->port); 
        var_dump($this->curl_connection);
    }

    // Setters
    public function setServer($newserver)
    {
        $this->server = $newserver;
    }

    public function setPort($newport)
    {
        $this->port = $newport;
    }

    public function setProxy($newproxy)
    {
        $this->proxy = $newproxy;
    }

    public function setTimeout($newtimeout)
    {
        $this->timeout = $newtimeout;
    }

    // Getters
    public function getServer()
    {
        echo $this->server;
        return $this->server;
    }

    public function curl_telnet($query) 
    {
        if (!function_exists('curl_init')) 
        { 
            user_error('"curl_init()" function does not exist.', E_USER_WARNING);
            return false; 
        }
        curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,$this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,$query);
        if($this->proxy != NULL)
        {
            echo "USING PROXY : ".$this->proxy."\n";
            curl_setopt($this->curl_connection,CURLOPT_PROXY,$this->proxy);
            curl_setopt($this->curl_connection,CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
        }
        $output=curl_exec($this->curl_connection); 
        //curl_close($this->curl_connection);
        if($output == false)
        {
            echo "CONNECTION ERROR!\n";
        }
        return $output; 
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $Destroy = curl_close($this->curl_connection);
        echo "Object destroyed (".$Destroy.")! \n";
    }
}

// Server,port,timeout,proxy(optional)
$ProxyAndPort = $Proxy.":".$ProxyPort;
$Smtp = new ProxySmtp($Server,$Port,$Timeout,$ProxyAndPort);
var_dump($Smtp->getServer());

var_dump($Smtp->curl_telnet("EHLO $User \r\n"));
var_dump($Smtp->curl_telnet("AUTH LOGIN \r\n"));
var_dump($Smtp->curl_telnet(base64_encode($user)." \r\n"));
var_dump($Smtp->curl_telnet(base64_encode($pass)." \r\n"));
var_dump($Smtp->curl_telnet("QUIT \r\n"));
```

witch gives me

```
string(389) "220 omta12.westchester.pa.mail.comcast.net comcast ESMTP server ready
250-omta12.westchester.pa.mail.comcast.net hello [85.204.11.249], pleased to meet you
250-HELP
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-SIZE 36700160
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250 OK
500 5.5.1 command unrecognized
500 5.5.1 command unrecognized
450 4.7.0 too many invalid commands (closing session)

....

....
```

and i have 6 questions that are troubling me very much:

1 WHY it gives me `500 5.5.1` and `450 4.7.0` at a simple `EHLO` command? This is not possible!

2 WHY the first example works with `fsockopen`, but the one with 'curl' witch i consider to be more powerful and have proxy functionality plus the objects and classes?

3 WHY this ProxySmtp class works on any other server just fine?

4 WHY i can replicate all that commands from above in cmd.exe (RAW style) and i can send the email?

5 Is it correct to use "\r\n" to say to telnet to "execute the line"?

6 Is it possible to "proxify" the first script? (make fsockopen to to trough a proxy)

**HINT**
For what i understood, you cannot send to COMCAST the command in a line like this:

```
$command  = "HELO smtp.comcast.net\r\n";
$command  .= "AUTH LOGIN\r\n";
$command  .= base64_encode("username")."\r\n";
$command  .= base64_encode("password")."\r\n";
$command .= "QUIT\r\n";

fwrite($connection,$command);
while (!feof($connection)) 
{
    echo fgets($connection, 128)."\n";
}
```

you must do it like this (LINE, SENT, LINE, SENT ...) :

```
$command  = "HELO smtp.comcast.net\r\n";
    fwrite($connection,$command);
    while (!feof($connection)) 
    {
        echo fgets($connection, 128)."\n";
    }

    $command  = "AUTH LOGIN\r\n";
    fwrite($connection,$command);
    while (!feof($connection)) 
    {
        echo fgets($connection, 128)."\n";
    }


    $command  = base64_encode("username")."\r\n";
    fwrite($connection,$command);
    while (!feof($connection)) 
    {
        echo fgets($connection, 128)."\n";
    }


    $command  = base64_encode("password")."\r\n";
    fwrite($connection,$command);
    while (!feof($connection)) 
    {
        echo fgets($connection, 128)."\n";
    }

    $command = "QUIT\r\n";
    fwrite($connection,$command);
    while (!feof($connection)) 
    {
        echo fgets($connection, 128)."\n";
    }
```

and it appears that CURL does not want to do this.

I really cannot possibly understand how is this not working, and need to use the PHP class because i should work with classes in order to build my WebMail server admin, and this is the first part, i have to go also into IMAP and POP3 protocols as well.